# UIRequiresPersistentWifi -- is this still available in 4.2?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, ipad

Previously one could add UIRequiresPersistentWiFi key to info.plist to keep wifi alive during user inactivity. Does anyone know if this is still available in 4.2 or if it has been replaced by another value? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the new plist editor for info.plist it is named "Application uses Wi-Fi" but still sets the same key as before. My concern was that I thought the key had been deprecated. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for it is unchanged. Why do you ask? Please elaborate on the particular problem you're trying to solve.